# Why not choosing the lowest minSdkVersion possible? What are the disadvantages?

Tags: android, gradle

If I create an Android-project and set the minSdkVersion to the lowest value possible and the targetSdkVersion to the most recent API, then would I accomplish the largest range possible. At least theoretically, I guess.

But I wonder:
**What are the disadvantages of setting the mindSdkVersion to a very low value?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the IDE(Android Studio) doesn't allow you to set a lower API level than 16.
Because of Gradle version and Androidx artifacts also it doesn't sync.

As a developer, we want to target as many supported devices as possible.
The reality is some functionalities won't work with lower API levels, security issues, and also performance.

These are the disadvantages that I can think of right now.